# Wordpress shortcode array unnamed attribute

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

Can't really get the hang of this. I'm trying to make a wordpress shortcode that gets values from an array in another file. What I'm trying to achieve is to make the shortcode 'myshortCode valueFromKey' work depending on the key.

This is my shortcode function in functions.php

```
function someCode($opts) {
    require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/php/array.php' );
    return $array[$opts[0]];
}add_shortcode('myshortCode', 'someCode');
```

And this is the array in array.php

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'a string respons...',
    'key2' => '...from external API'
);
```

But no matter what I do I can only get the first key value from the array. e.g.

'myshortCode key1'

'myshortCode key2'

only returns 'myshortCode key1'

I plan on using this to display respons data from an external API. So all of these shortcodes will be in different sections on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested the code and it works fine on my side

[myshortCode "key1" "key2"] this is how I called the shortcode

and this is what I have included into my functions.php

Not to call the file many times just declare the array above the function or include the file once above the function.

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/array.php' );
```

OR

```
$array = array('key' => 'value');
```

Then inside the function just write global $array; to access the variables declared outside the function.

```
function someCode($opts) {
    global $array;

    return $array[$opts[1]];

}
add_shortcode('myshortCode', 'someCode');
```

Make sure you have `<?php` in the beginning of your array.php file and make sure path is correct. All the rest should be fine.

```
$opts
```

is an array of your unnamed attributes so you can choose $opts[0], $opts[1] and so on..

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it's not working. All paths are correct and no tags (i.e. <?php) are incomplete. There is something in the syntax I'm not getting. Maybe I need to clarify. I'm going to be using the shortcode on several places on the same page where the attributes should decide what content to get (i.e. I can't be inserting [$opt[0]]). Might not have clarified my question better. I need to get different content from the array, based on the returned attribute in the shortcode (e.g. 'ashortcode key1' returns the value from key1 in the array. I believe my return has to change.

Comment: So if you will use [myshortCode "key1"] then it should display "a string respons..." and if you use [myshortCode "key2"] you will get  "...from external API" return. (You will use $opts[0]). This functionality works perfectly fine on my side.

Comment: Sorry just checked and if the shortcode is used twice then it break. Let me check further.

Comment: OK, here is a solution: use require instead of require_once

Comment: Hmm, interesting. In my actual source code I have another require_once (in the "array.php" (to connect to the API)). This one also has to be require for this to work. However... I'm wondering what the differens is? I understand that require_once only fires once. What I'm wondering is if this will result in a massive amount of calls to the API? Eventually there are going to be hundreds of array keys. And since I've already gotten the respons (with all the data I need to build the array, I don't want it to send a new request for each array key  :)

Comment: The case is that if the shortcode is ran twice then when using require once the file will get fetched only once and second time it will not be accessed. Maybe it should be a better way to declare $array outside of the functions and then inside the function call global $array; and then use that array. This way you would call it once and then use it many times as a global variable.

Comment: That sounds like a legitimate course of action! I'm assuming this would allow the require_once to work again? I'm not really to savvy with PHP (I get by so to speak)... Would you mind showing an example of how I could execute this in you answer?  :)

Comment: Almost there! :P  Only problem now is that the whole wordpress site is broken (when I place the require_once outside of the short code function). I'm guessing because now it requiring the file all the time, which of course can't be right?  :)

Comment: This already depends on the file that is being required. if it has just opening of php tag and then the array than it should work fine. On my side it is working. What's in your file that you are requiring? :)

Comment: nwm, first of I noticed a typo :P  second I think I understand a little better now. I've split up the file into parts, so the actual array is created in a separat file outside the function (there are 3 parts, request.php (called once in the function), connect.php (the credentials for the API. Reused in other places) called once from request, and response.php (calling the request.php once) building the array outside of the function. It looks like everything is working fine now  :)

Comment: Good to hear :) Good luck with your project! :)